# How to load XLS or XLSX data file directly on a SQL Server table using DNN

Tags: sql-server, excel, dotnetnuke, xls, xlsx

I'm quite new on DNN and I'm in charge of figuring out how a existing site on DNN works and manage it the same time.

Client asked me an easy way, as administrator, to load a XLS or XLSX file on a table on SQL Server. Do you know which extension does that? Or I'll need to develop one to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Lucas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you could do this, but here are a few:

1. Write a module or scheduled job that loads the XLS file from a specific location into the database.  This would require knowledge on how to write DNN modules
2. If they are Admins, grant them access to the SQL module.  DNN has a module that allows you to run SQL directly.  You could write some SQL that could load the XLS file from a specific location. This is not a good solution, but it would work.
3. I'm sure there are 3rd party modules that do this, so check the DNN Store.